Source code displays "_N_E" in Production for Next.js App with Sentry
I'm developing a Next.js application and have integrated Sentry for error tracking. However, when deploying the app in production, the source code is displayed as "_N_E" in Google Chrome's Developer. I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve this, ensuring the source code is properly shown in production.
const { withSentryConfig } = require("@sentry/nextjs");

const nextConfig = {
  output: 'standalone',
  productionBrowserSourceMaps: true,
  trailingSlash: true,
  modularizeImports: {
    '@mui/icons-material': {
      transform: '@mui/icons-material/{{member}}',
    },
    '@mui/material': {
      transform: '@mui/material/{{member}}',
    },
    '@mui/lab': {
      transform: '@mui/lab/{{member}}',
    },
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });
    return config;
  },
  sentry: {
    hideSourceMaps: true,
    disableLogger: true,
    transpileClientSDK: true,
  },
};

const sentryWebpackPluginOptions = {
  silent: true,
  // Project details redacted
  tunnelRoute: "/monitoring",
};

module.exports = withSentryConfig(nextConfig, sentryWebpackPluginOptions);


Attempted Solutions:
Ensured productionBrowserSourceMaps is set to true in my Next.js configuration.
Checked Sentry configuration for any misconfigurations that might hide source maps.
Searched for similar issues but found none that resolve the "_N_E" display issue.
Question:
Has anyone encountered this issue or can offer insights into why the source code is being displayed as "_N_E" in the production environment? Any advice on debugging or resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Context:
I am adding a screenshot of the Google Chrome source code where "_N_E" is displayed. (Note: Remember to attach the screenshot when posting on Stack Overflow).

